# unable to clone the github repository 'prework-study-guide' to the directory, 'bootcamp'

Tags: github, directory, command, repository, clone

Every time I try the command, " git clone '<git@gitub.com...prework-study-guide.git>' I get this messsage:

Cloning into 'prework-study-guide.git>'...
<git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I've tried updating the view of my repository to private, then back to public. Checked that I used the correct licence, then tried again. The terminal still gave the same response. Within GitHub, the repository I created definitely exists.

Comment: If that's an exact quote of your command, it won't work for sure, with those angle brackets. It should be `git clone git@github.com...prework-study-quite.git` or maybe with single quotes, but certainly not with angle braces.

Comment: If that's not an exact quote of your command, please edit your question to quote it exactly. Place code in a code block, so text is preserved here exactly as on your terminal.